# How to make jupyter HTML-matplotlib animation with seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, jupyter, seaborn

I trying to make `HTML(anim.to_html5_video)` animation work in jupyter with seaborn heatmap.

- First, I get working working samples from documentation, and make "pure matplotlib" [image map animated example](https://github.com/belonesox/wtf-jupyter-animation-seaborn/blob/master/wtf-animation-worked.ipynb), it worked, with small problem ("parasite output" in animation cell)
- Then, I tried to [make it work with seaborn.heatmap](https://github.com/belonesox/wtf-jupyter-animation-seaborn/blob/master/wtf-heatmap-animation.ipynb)… but failed. Animation looks like "infinite mirror" — obviously something wrong with matplotlib axes/plot composition, but I can't get it.

Common initialization cell:

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
#%matplotlib notebook # Tried both, not needed for animation.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation, rc
from IPython.display import HTML
```

Animation worked, but "unwanted static output image exists":

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx = 50
ny = 50

line2d, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line2d.set_data([], [])
    ax.imshow(np.zeros((nx, ny)))
    return (line2d,)

def animate(i):
    data = np.random.rand(nx, ny)
    ax.set_title('i: ' + str(i))    
    ax.imshow(data)
    return (line2d,)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=10, interval=1000, blit=False)

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

So, looks that all OK with my jupyter setup (packages, ffmpeg, etc).

But, I cannot get how to make it with seaborn.heatmap:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
nx = 50
ny = 50

line2d, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

ax_global = ax

def init_heatmap():
    line2d.set_data([], [])
    sns.heatmap(np.zeros((nx, ny)), ax=ax_global)
    return (line2d,)


def animate_heatmap(i):
    data = np.random.rand(nx, ny)
    sns.heatmap(data, ax=ax_global)
    ax.set_title('Frame: ' + str(i))    

    return (line2d,)

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate_heatmap, init_func=init_heatmap,
                              frames=10, interval=1000, blit=True)

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

Both samples ready to [test on github](https://github.com/belonesox/wtf-jupyter-animation-seaborn)

Of course, I want to see animation with random map and "stable heat-axes"
but get this
https://vimeo.com/298786185/

Answer (score 3):

You can toggle the "colorbar". From the Seaborn.heatmap [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html), you need to change `sns.heatmap(data, ax=ax_global)` to `sns.heatmap(data, ax=ax_global, cbar=False)` and also do the same inside the `init_heatmap()`.